# Are there any difference between `Widget.MaterialComponents.LinearProgressIndicator.MyStyleName` and `MyStyleName`?

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-styles, material-components-android

Are there any difference between `Widget.MaterialComponents.LinearProgressIndicator.MyStyleName` and `MyStyleName`?

```
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.LinearProgressIndicator.MyStyleName" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.LinearProgressIndicator">
    <item name="trackColor">@color/green</item>
    <item name="indicatorColor">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
</style>

<style name="MyStyleName" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.LinearProgressIndicator">
    <item name="trackColor">@color/green</item>
    <item name="indicatorColor">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
</style>
```

And can I apply `MyStyleName` directly to linearProgressIndicator without using this line?

```
<item name="linearProgressIndicatorStyle">@style/MyStyleName</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the style name is different, both styles are inheriting same parent style.
Yes you can apply `MystyleName` directly to ur linearProgressIndicator by using style attribute like this :

```
style="@style/MyStyleName"
```

Add this line in the `LinearProgressIndicator` xml code.